# mongodb high resource usage and configuration hints

Tags: mongodb, configuration, cpu-usage

I am running a MongoDB instance as a ubuntu service, on a VM with enough resources to handle it with ease, the system is on-premise and not Cloud.
I am a newbie with MongoDB and this is a test/dev environment.

The problem I am getting right now is an abnormal usage of CPU and RAM resources, due to a huge amount of MongoDB threads running and hanging around.

Here's [an HTOP resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AN5lU.png) and a strace of the worse of those bad guys.

```
sudo strace -p 973
strace: Process 973 attached
futex(0x5644b5e929e8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
strace: Process 973 detached
<detached ...>
```

other than a possible solution, can you advise me on any interesting articles about setting and configuring Mongo to run for production?

other info:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

> db.version()
4.2.7
```

Comment: Read the MongoDB production notes as a start https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/

Comment: check. I don't think anything major is out of place. atm, I'm not doing any sharding but also I am working on a DB smaller than 1GB.
If you need any other reports or info, just ask.

Comment: Actually, only the CPU is going crazy. ram is fine.

Comment: How much ram do you have? What else is running on your machine? Are you the only one querying the database?

Comment: Hello Joe, I have 32GB of RAM, of which currently, I use less than 3.
My application's backed is the only one querying the DB and the machine is hosting the application itself, Nginx and node-red. resources used by other stuff is very low atm.

Comment: Why are you running so many copies of mongod? Is this a very large replica set or a sharded cluster?

Comment: none of those. for what I can understand about the inner workings, this is just multithreaded indexing and querying. (wiredTiger?)
there is only one machine and one mongod running as a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

apparently one of my collections was growing too big and I was executing various aggregate pipelines on it.

It ended up clogging the machine, solved with some tweaks to the structure :)